# Mo.js alternative for object spread syntax

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm following the mo.js tutorials and am working on the circle click burst portion.

```
const OPTS = {
  fill:           'none',
  radius:         25,
  strokeWidth:    { 50 : 0 },
  scale:          { 0: 1 },
  angle:          { 'rand(-35, -70)': 0 },
  duration:       500,
  left: 0,        top: 0,
  easing: 'cubic.out'
};

const circle1 = new mojs.Shape({
  ...OPTS,
  stroke:         'cyan',
});

const circle2 = new mojs.Shape({
  ...OPTS,
  radius:         { 0 : 15 },
  strokeWidth:    { 30: 0 },
  stroke:         'magenta',
  delay:          'rand(75, 150)'
});
```

I'm using VSCode V 1.7.2 which is having trouble supporting the `...` syntax. I am also getting console errors in Chrome 54.0.2840.99. Is there an equivalent format I can use to get around this problem? I'm imagining something like `options: OPTS` would work, but I haven't seen anything in the documentation or on the internet to help me out.

Obviously I can just replicate the properties in OPTS in the circle declarations, but I want to know how to use the OPTS variable for simplicity.

I would tag mo.js, but I don't have enough reputation to create a new tag.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Object.assign()` instead:

```
const circle2 = new mojs.Shape(Object.assign({}, OPTS, {
  radius:         { 0 : 15 },
  strokeWidth:    { 30: 0 },
  stroke:         'magenta',
  delay:          'rand(75, 150)'
}));
```

Object spread is still a proposal, and the linter doesn't recognize the syntax. It doesn't mean it won't work. If you're using babel with [stage 3 preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-3/) (or 0, 1, 2 presets), for example, it will work, even if vscode shows a warning. I'm not familiar with vscode, but you can probably add support for this feature.

Comment: you've got the order wrong. `OPTS` should be first to retain the same functionality, but you'll also need a blank `{}` in there to avoid modifying `OPTS`.

Comment: Thanks. Haven't thought about the override.